# re-arrange values in one column without affecting other columns using awk or sed

Tags: sed, awk, columns

I have a csv file in following format:

```
abc,124,123,2014-08-13,abc
def,124,123,2014-08-13,abc
ghi,124,123,2014-08-13,abc
```

Now I need to modify only 5th column (`2014-08-13`) to produce output as given below

```
abc,124,123,13/08/2014,abc
def,124,123,13/08/2014,abc
ghi,124,123,13/08/2014,abc
```

One liner `awk` or `sed` solutions would be preferred if possible.

Comment: Suggest `perl -pe` instead...

Comment: Ben, thanks for suggestion, could you please provide complete syntax which would help me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'[,-]' '{printf "%s,%s,%s,%s/%s/%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $6, $5, $4, $7}' file
```

**Explanation**:

- `-F'[,-]`: set the delimiter to `,` or `-`
- `'{printf "%s,%s,%s,%s/%s/%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $6, $5, $4, $7}'`: print the part in the desired order and a newline at the end.

And a `sed` solution:

```
sed 's|\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)|\3/\2/\1|g' file
```

**Explanation**:

- `\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)-\([0-9]*\)`: search for digits-dash-digits-dash-digits (save the digits in subpatterns `\1`, `\2` and `\3`)
- `\3/\2/\1` and replace them in reverse order with `/` in-between.

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -aF'[,-]' -ne 'print join ",", @F[0..2], join("/", @F[5,4,3]), $F[6]' < input
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
$ sed -e 's#\([0-9]\{1,\}\)-\([0-9]\{1,\}\)-\([0-9]\{1,\}\)#\3/\2/\1#' file
abc,124,123,13/08/2014,abc
def,124,123,13/08/2014,abc
ghi,124,123,13/08/2014,abc
```

If you have GNU or FreeBSD `sed`, you can use:

```
sed -E 's#([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)#\3/\2/\1#' file
```

or `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's#(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)#$3/$2/$1#'
```

Comment: @VinothKumarN, if this resolved your issue, please accept the answer as a note of thank you to the user who helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another awk solution

```
awk -F, -va="([0-9]+)" '$0=gensub((a"-"a"-"a),"\\3/\\2/\\1","g")' file
```

`-F,` Sets field separator as comma

`-va="([0-9]+)"` Sets a variable(a) as the regex in the quotes.

`([0-9]+)` This regex matches any number of number in the range of 0-9(so all numbers really) and is within brackets so the match is saved.

`$0=gensub` Sets $0(the line) to the result of gensub

`(a"-"a"-"a)` Uses the regex from before to match 'number' 'dash' 'number' 'dash' 'number'

`,"\\3/\\2/\\1","g")` Reverses the order of the saved matched and adds `/` between them, not that the - are not in brackets and so are not saved.`g` just means it applies to all matches.

Comment: Please add what your command does as it would benefit the future readers :)

Comment: @Ramesh there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution

```
awk -F ',' '{split($4, a, "-"); $4 = (a[3] "/" a[2] "/" a[1])}1' OFS=, file
```